# How to change User Logon Name Suffix in AD?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I need to change each users UPN Suffix in Active Directory, but it can not be changed via the visual interface.

I have tried to do it in bulk, but I am not allowed to change the UPN Suffix to all users.

`PS C:\> Set-ADUser -Identity CorgiTopi -UserPrincipalName CTopi@centria.com`

I expect the UPN to be `CTopi@centria.com`, but the actual result is `CTopi@centria.com@centria.gb`

Comment: Do you see `centria.com` listed as a domain or upn suffix when running `get-adforest | select domains,upnsuffixes`? if not, you need to add it as a suffix first.

Comment: Yes, centria.com is listed as a UPN suffix but not as a domain. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: UPN suffix should be good enough if it is not the name of your AD domain.

Comment: I can change it via the user interface, but I can not change it via Powershell.

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. If you surround the UPN in single quotes, is the result the same? `Set-ADUser -Identity CorgiTopi -UserPrincipalName 'CTopi@centria.com'`. Maybe you should post the entire code block for this process because something could be appended accidentally. Maybe the code is taking `$UPN + $domain` where `$UPN` already includes the domain you want.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply :) Let me explain you the context. We are using Automation anywhere to create a new AD User. First, we need to create the user in the resource forest(e.g CSA.gb) then we create that user in our own domain( CENTRIA.GB).

Comment: You are right, maybe the code is taking $UPN + $domain.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this either. It works as expected when I try it. Maybe it's a difference in versions of the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet, or more likely something else going on in your code.

If using the `-UserPrincipalName` parameter is automatically adding the domain name for you, then you can try using the `-Replace` parameter. It should just do what you tell it without any additional processing of your value.

```
Set-ADUser -Identity CorgiTopi -Replace @{userPrincipalName="CTopi@centria.com"}
```

Side note that's probably not relevant to you: it's not actually required to add the UPN suffix to the domain for it to work. You can update the `userPrincipalName` to whatever you want. For example, this will even work:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity CorgiTopi -Replace @{userPrincipalName="CTopi@stackoverflow.com"}
```

It's just AD Users and Computers that forces you to use one of the alternate UPN suffixes registered on the domain.

But I'm not suggesting anyone not add an alternate UPN suffix if they're going to use it.